# Format date in the output of a PowerShell query

Tags: powershell

PowerShell nubie question. How do I format the date in a PowerShell query result? Example command:

```
get-adcomputer -Filter {operatingsystem -like "Windows 10*"} -Properties operatingsystemversion, lastlogon | select-object name, operatingsystemversion, @{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}} | select name, operatingsystemversion, lastlogon
```

The output looks like this:

> PCName        10.0 (19045)           4/27/2023 2:30:16 PM

and I'd like to show just the year and month like this:

> PCName        10.0 (19045)           2023-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for (at least it works on my machine).

```
get-adcomputer -Filter {operatingsystem -like "Windows 10*"} -Properties operatingsystemversion, lastlogondate | select-object name, operatingsystemversion, @{n='LastLogon';e={Get-Date $_.lastlogondate -Format yyyy-MM}} | select name, operatingsystemversion, lastlogon
```